# Symfony 6 custom form, rendering name of input

Tags: symfony6

I havw customized forms in my Symfony project.I need to display name of input as placeholder directly in input. I did this:

```
{% block text_widget %}
    <div class="input_placeholder"   style="width: 244px; background-color: white;">
        <div class="input_frame" style="width: 244px; background-color: white;">
            <input type="text" class="input_field" id="{{ id }}" name="{{ full_name }}" placeholder="{{name}}"/>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Problem is that the name is not formated, it is actualy a name of the variable in format:"user_name", but I need format: "User name". And I also need to translate this. Does anybody have an idea how can I achieve this goals?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom Twig Filter for format the name as you wish.

```
{% block text_widget %}
    <div class="input_placeholder"   style="width: 244px; background-color: white;">
        <div class="input_frame" style="width: 244px; background-color: white;">
            <input type="text" class="input_field" id="{{ id }}" name="{{ full_name }}" placeholder="{{name|custom_filter}}"/>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

[Here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#templates-twig-extension) you can check how to define custom filters in twig.